# sending email with ssl using javax.mail

Tags: java, email

i want to send an email using gmail as smtp server.

this is my code, and i do not get it to work...
after running testSettings() i get the debug output and then it just stops. no timeout, no error, nothing....

```
public void testSettings() {
    final String username = Settings.get("benutzername");
    final String password = Settings.get("passwort");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", Settings.get("port"));
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", Settings.get("server"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", Settings.get("port"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.timeout", "10000");

    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", "false");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
    props.put("mail.smtp.connectiontimeout", "10000");

    props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
            });
    session.setDebug(true);
    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("myemail@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("myemail@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("test");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        transport.send(message);
        // Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning     javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
```

The following error occurs:
http://pastie.org/private/rkoknss6ppiufjd9swqta

Comment: Did you try the solution provided in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1990454/using-javamail-to-connect-to-gmail-smtp-server-ignores-specified-port-and-tries)?

Comment: yes, nothing changes... still no error.. it just hangs

Comment: please see my edit for error message.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Instead of

> props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");
>
> Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");

Use

> props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
>
> Transport transport =session.getTransport("smtp");

Use **smtp**, not smtps

I used JDK 8, Netbeans 8, JavaMail 1.5.2 and this example **works fine**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465"); 
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username@gmail.com","password");
            }
        });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("frommail@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("tomail@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Test Mail");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

If you are not able connect with port 465, try port 587

Comment: yeah i believe this works. i tested this some days ago on my laptop  but on my desktop i cannot get it to work... and i do not know why...

Comment: i just copied your code, created a new java project, filled in my data and then tested it. and it still does not happen anything.

Comment: I used java 8, netbeans 8 and JavaMail API 1.5.2 tested and worked without any problem, and send mail myself, everything ok. Check your connection to smtp.gmail com 465 port, you can use telnet for it. Latest JavaMail API: https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release

Comment: mhhh when i telnet smtp.gmail.com 465 with putty, a blank screen opens and  also nothing happens :<

Comment: this shows that you have connection, what java version use? if java version and api version different, some problems may occur

Comment: i use the latest java jdk 1.8_0_25, but finally got it working with port 587 instead of 465. you should add this to your answer then i can mark it

Comment: Thanks for your post but I was not able to connect using SSL unless smpts protocol is used. A solution that worked for me is at http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0570.html

Comment: Thanks but Gmail ask me to enable allow not secure applications. Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 27):

From reading this: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#commonmistakes

The use of

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
        "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");**
```

and

```
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
```

is kind of outdated. To simplify the code, use:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you using Windows and have any Antivirus or firewall disable it and try.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in computer name, it was contain cyrillic symbols. For understanding reason of your problem add

```
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
```

Also see work code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13655063/javamail-api-how-do-you-change-setfrom-to-whatever-you-want)